# How to mount directory from vagrant box on local FS using SSHFS?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, vagrant, sshfs

**I want to mount the / of the vagrant box on to the local fs using sshfs**.

*the command i used was*

```
sshfs hadoopuser@192.168.0.106:/ .
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.106 (192.168.0.106)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 9d:80:94:dc:f1:c4:bc:30:2d:e0:e2:7e:7c:5d:46:e3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
hadoopuser@192.168.0.106's password: 
hadoopuser@192.168.0.106's password: 
hadoopuser@192.168.0.106's password: 
read: Connection reset by peer
```

how do i solve this problem? 
And

- where do i find the public key for my machine
- Where do i keep it on the other machine so that the login authentication is done via keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu your keys are stored in

```
/home/<user>/.ssh/
```

you will need your public key `id_rsa.pub`.

If you don't have it then do

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

On your remote server you'll need to copy your public key into

```
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

either manually copy/paste or using commands like

```
ssh-copy-id <username>@<host>
```

or if you need to copy someone else's public key do

```
scp id_rsa.pub <username>@<host>:/root/.ssh/ #copies file to remote server
ssh <username>@<host> # login to remote server
cd /root/.ssh/ # go to copied file
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys # concatenate it onto the authorized_keys
```

Source: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)